# Taxes is not shown in the cart. Using Drupal Commerce module

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using the Drupal Commerce module and I need to add some taxes to be shown in the cart.

Then, I added 2 taxes in admin/commerce/config/taxes following this video directions: [video](http://vimeo.com/22096163)

First one is a VAT tax type which is shown correctly

Second one is a Sales Taxes tax type which is not shown at all in the cart

What am I missing? As far as I can see is not a permission related problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal commerce will by default not show taxes on the cart, the cart is more simple minded with focus on products. The review and checkout pages, will however have taxes displayed by default.

The shopping cart is based on views, so it's pretty easy to change how the order total is displayed. Instead of using `Commerce Line Item: Line item summary` area handler you should instead use the `Commerce Order: Total`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I had to make changes to the cart views to make the Sales Taxes visible.

Comment: It works but the button (update and checkout) are now above total and taxes amounts. Look a the capture I've done: http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/3563/screenshot03zq.jpg . Where do I change this?

Comment: @chefnelone Right, I had forgotten about that. The easiest solution is to use CSS to position them differently. I talked with Ryan at Drupalcon London and looked into this. The short explanation, is that the way Views work, it's not possible to change the markup, since the buttons comes from a views form and the summary from an area handler. (It's possible but I believe it requires changes in Views and a a lot of rewrite of some Commerce Views integration)

Comment: I understand, so I will let the css do its magic. thanks.